# JQuery Slider handle is not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using JQuery UI Slider along with Highcharts framework, and I am not able to move the slider handle.

The issue can be reproducible by accessing the below mentioned URL link:

http://74.209.247.77/testing.html

There are two question items, the first question item is a multiple choice question item which is displayed initially when the page is loaded, and when we click on the "Next" button in the page then the Bar Graph question item is displayed where we can reproduce the issue, the slider handle will not move when clicked on it and dragged.

Comment: Please include the HTML/JS you used to create the chart.

Comment: Hi dlsso, I tried integrating the code in the JSFiddle, but there were some errors showing up and also the size of the code is exceeding the limitation. So I have directly placed my HTML file in our webserver and provided the following link.  http://74.209.247.77/testing.html  If we access this URL and view the page source then you can see all the HTML and JS code. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe better is using [draggable points](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points) extension which allows to resize columns.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, using draggable points can we achieve the same look and feel and similar functionality as it is existing currently? Since the users are already using this functionality in an application that is running on some old technology. Now when we are upgrading the application to the latest technologies then we are getting this issue with the JQuery Slider handle not moving.